# Not able to get performance even after creating composite as well as simple indexes(regular and Bit map) as well

Tags: indexing, oracle11g, query-optimization, query-performance, database-tuning

I am working on a query optimization task and i have a set of queries which are being used by my application and supports all (Oracle, Ms Sql Server and MySql) databases.

My table structure:

```
User_Info {
id              int primary key
user_name       String       /*can have duplicate names*/
modified_date   date         /*can have duplicate dates*/
action          String      /*have some set of pre-defined actions only*/
url             String      /*have maximum number of uniqueness*/

}
```

But now the size of this table has been increased to **7 million records**.

Below is the duplicate record count for some of columns which are being used in query:

- **user_name**: john has 5 692 214 duplicates and
- **action**:    Actions1 has 5 812 590 duplicates and Actions2 has 194 999 duplicates

and all queries (combination of any of these: **user_name, action, modified_date and url** columns can be used in query) are just returning the count of all rows and all the columns using pagination:

**Example of my query** :

```
select * from (
select info.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( order by info.modified_date DESC) rn from (
select info.*, Count(*) OVER () AS info_count from (
select * from User_Info info  where  ( info.url LIKE 'url://%' ) AND (info.action = 'Action1' ) AND info.user_name ='john' and info.modified_date >= '04/01/2014 00:00:00'  and info.modified_date <= '04/12/2014 23:59:59'
) info 
) info 
) info 
WHERE rn >= 1 and rn <=100;
```

but the problem is, they all are taking approx 100 sec
I tried creating all possible types of combined as well as single indexes as well and tested on all but no solution. It is improved after adding indexes but not at satisfactory level

I need all queries to complete in max. 10 second

**Current indexes which i tried are**:

```
CREATE INDEX INX_USER_INFO_D4 ON USER_INFO(MODIFIED_DATE DESC, USER_NAME, URL, ACTION) COMPRESS;
CREATE INDEX INX_USER_INFO_U2 ON USER_INFO(USER_NAME, ACTION) COMPRESS; 
CREATE INDEX INX_USER_INFO_DATED ON USER_INFO(MODIFIED) COMPRESS;
```

How can i design my indexes so that it could cover all scenario's with performance?

Comment: Please run `EXPLAIN  PLAN SELECT a-rest-of-your-query`, then `SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.Display`, and then copy a result of last query and append it to the question in e text format (use EDIT option).More on `explain plan` command you can find [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#g42231).

Comment: thanks for the link @krokodilko, i have already tried this option but not sure if it shows correct result everytime.

Comment: Have you tried indexes on `USER_INFO(ACTION, USER_NAME MODIFIED_DATE DESC )` or  `USER_INFO(ACTION, USER_NAME, URL, MODIFIED_DATE DESC )` ?

Comment: yes exactly same i tried. it is good but also i need for others queries as well. So it would be very helpful for me if you could suggest any link or something which i can refer to get knowledge about how optimizer really decides that which index can be used.

Comment: Well, then plase also show other queries you want to optimize. There is no all-purpose index which would be best for all possible queries, but maybe the re is some trade-off

Comment: @krokodilko i agree with your ans that there is no all-purpose index but is there any way to find out by which i get to know that what type of index is required on which column?

Answer (score 0):

For this **concrete query**:

```
select * 
from (
   select info.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( order by info.modified_date DESC) rn 
   from (
      select info.*, Count(*) OVER () AS info_count 
      from (
          select * from User_Info info  
          where  
                ( info.url LIKE 'url://%' ) 
            AND (info.action = 'Action1' ) 
            AND info.user_name ='john' 
            and info.modified_date >= '04/01/2014 00:00:00'  
            and info.modified_date <= '04/12/2014 23:59:59'
      ) info 
   ) info 
) info 
WHERE rn >= 1 and rn <=100;
```

in my own guesstimate, **without seeing an explain plan of this query**, looking only on the query and the table structure, the best results may (or may not) give a multicolumn index on `info( action , user_name, modified_date )`.
Please create this index, then refresh statistics, then generate the explain plan and measure a query time, and we will see.
The optimizer can use this index, but may ignore it as well, nobody knows.